# Simple logic problem: Finding largest and smallest number among 3 numbers

Tags: language-agnostic, logic

I am creating a pseudocode in determining the smallest and largest number among 3 numbers:

My code is as follows:

```
If (x >= y)  
   largest = x
   Smallest = y
Else 
    largest = y
    Smallest =x

If (z >= largest)
    Largest = z
If (z <= smallest)
    Smallest = z
```

Do you think this is correct? or are there better ways to solve this?

Comment: It should work, if no two numbers are equal.

Comment: but what if 2 numbers are equal? why wouldn't it work?

Comment: 3,3,3. It might be good if the logic says all the numbers are equal. Though it is obvious that all the numbers are equal when the greatest and smallest are equal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's say you've got arbitrary numbers `x, y, z`.

Pseudocode:

```
largest = x
smallest = x

if (y > largest)  then largest = y
if (z > largest)  then largest = z

if (y < smallest) then smallest = y
if (z < smallest) then smallest = z
```

This is one way to solve your problem if you're using only variables, assignment, if-else and comparison.

---

If you have arrays and a sort operation defined over it, you can use this:

```
array = [x, y, z]
arrays.sort()
largest  = array[2]
smallest = array[0]
```

---

If you have a `max` and `min` function that takes an array of numbers as an argument, you can use this:

```
array = [x, y, z]
largest  = max(array)
smallest = min(array)
```

---

If you also have positional assignment using sets, you can use this:

```
array = [x, y, z]
(largest, smallest) = (max(array), min(array))
```

---

If you have a data structure that will sort it's contents when inserting elements, you can use this:

```
array.insert([x, y, z])
smallest = array[0]
largest = array[2]
```

Comment: On a rather academic side: Your algorithm has O(n log n) complexity. It can be done with O(n)...

Comment: @Lukas: I'd say it's O(1) either way :)

Comment: @abeln: `n` is the number of elements in the array for the general solution (in case there are more than 3 elements. you see, quite academic... ;-) )

Comment: @Lukas: I see only 3 numbers and no "general" solution (if there are n numbers, array[2] won't give you the maximum). I get your point, though.

Comment: @Lukas: I didn't specify what algorithm `sort` uses ;-)

Comment: @darioo, if your algorithm is faster than `O(n log n)` then I congratulate to your nobel prize ;-)

Comment: @Lukas: no, it's not; I will leave that discovery to greater minds of our time. If I go and implement a sort algorithm, it will certainly be `O(n log n)` or (more probably) slower than that ;-)

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main ( int argc, char **argv ) {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 3;

    printf ( "MAX = %d\n", max(a,max(b,c)));
    printf ( "MIN = %d\n", min(a,min(b,c)));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would be more general (in Java):

```
// All available values.
int[] values = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

// Initialise smallest and largest to the extremes
int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

// Compare every value with the previously discovered
// smallest and largest value
for (int value : values) {

  // If the current value is smaller/larger than the previous
  // smallest/largest value, update the reference
  if (value < smallest) smallest = value;
  if (value > largest) largest = value;
}

// Here smallest and largest will either hold the initial values
// or the smallest and largest value in the values array
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (x < y) {
  minimum = min(x,z)
  maximum = max(y,z)
} else {
  minimum = min(y,z)
  maximum = max(x,z)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Represent numbers with a, b, and c, assuming no two numbers are equal.

Read the three numbers

- If a is less than b, then if a is less than c
  print a, otherwise print c
- If b is less than a, then if b is less than c
  print b, otherwise print c